# Optimizar consumo batería app android

Tags: android

He desarrollado una `app` en `android`, pero algunos usuarios me han comentado que de vez en cuando su móvil les manda una notificación de que mi `app` esta consumiendo mucha batería.

¿Como puedo **optimizar el consumo de batería** o monitorizarlo para saber en que punto consume mas?

Tengo activado las notificaciones push con firebase y también el crashlitycs reporting, no se si eso afectará.

Comment: Espero mi respuesta te ayude :) . saludos

Comment: Agrega más detalles, que tiene tu aplicación usa GPS, que procesos ? @AlbertoMier

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser por muchos motivos, podrías verificar lo siguiente:

- Si estás usando Firebase Realtime Database verifica que estés
  quitando los listener cuando tu aplicación no está activa.
- Que tu aplicación no esté realizando tareas en segundo plano que
  impliquen consumo de datos.
- Evita la creación de objetos innecesarios.
- Revisa los listener/subscripciones que tengas dentro de tu app y no
  te olvides de hacer el unregister/unsubscribe cuando no lo necesites.
- Evita guardar muchos objetos en memoria usando Static.

Android Studio provee herramientas para que puedes monitorear el consumo de memoria de tu aplicación, para más información te dejo este enlace:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html