# ¿Firebase Messaging O GCM?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Tengo una `app` en la que uso `Firebase Messaging`, pero tengo problemas de consumo de batería. Y leyendo en los [docs de google](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), recomiendan que para ahorrar batería se use `GCM`.

Así que mi pregunta es: **¿Cual es la diferencia entre usar `GCM` o `FirebaseMessaging`?**

Comment: Espero te ayude mi respuesta

Comment: Hola @AlbertoMier Alberto, usas FCM tienes problemas de consumo de Batería, lo has comparado con GCM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**¿Cual es la diferencia entre usar GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) o FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)?**

En realidad no debe ser opción el implementar GCM ya que **se debe migrar a FCM**, puedes revisar el mensaje que indica lo que comento, esto al ingresar a la [documentación de Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) es la nueva versión de GCM. ¡Hereda la
>   infraestructura de GCM confiable y escalable, además de nuevas
>   características! Vea las preguntas frecuentes para obtener más
>   información. Si está integrando mensajes en una nueva aplicación,
>   comience con FCM. **Se recomienda encarecidamente a los usuarios de GCM
>   actualizar a FCM para beneficiarse de las nuevas funciones de FCM hoy
>   y en el futuro.** ¡Antes de partir, visite nuestra encuesta para
>   desarrolladores de GCM y FCM para darnos su opinión!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque FCM hereda de la infraestructura de GCM, **características como el consumo de memoria entre una y otra implementación no son lo mismo**, de hecho el consumo de batería usando FCM es una de las mejoras ya que esta mejor optimizado con respecto a GCM.

---

**Las diferencias entre GCM y FCM son:**

- FCM Simplifica el desarrollo del cliente. Ya no se tiene que escribir una lógica de reintento de registro o suscripción. Método onTokenRefresh():
- Habilita una nueva solución de notificaciones sin servidor con una consola web, Firebase Notifications. Con las notificaciones de Firebase, cualquier persona puede enviar notificaciones a públicos específicos basados en las estadísticas de Firebase Analytics. Luego pueden evaluar la efectividad de las notificaciones evaluando el Análisis de Embudo de Notificaciones incorporado en la consola.
- Si tienes implementado GCM, al migrar a FCM no se necesitará realizar ningún cambio en el lado del servidor para la actualización. El protocolo de servicio no ha cambiado. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que todas las mejoras de servidor nuevas se documentarán en la documentación del servidor de FCM.

[Migración cliente de GCM a FCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm)

---

En cuanto a el consumo de batería FCM esta mejor optimizado con respecto a GCM, sin embargo estas consideraciones aplican tanto para GCM como para FCM

[Configuración de la prioridad de un mensaje](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#configuracin-de-la-prioridad-de-un-mensaje)

Tienes dos opciones para asignar una prioridad de entrega a los mensajes descendentes: prioridad normal y alta. La entrega de los mensajes con prioridad normal o alta funciona de la siguiente manera:

- Prioridad normal. Esta es la prioridad predeterminada para los mensajes de datos. Los mensajes con prioridad normal no abrirán conexiones de red en un dispositivo inactivo y su mensaje podría retrasarse para conservar la batería. Para los mensajes menos urgentes, como las notificaciones de correos electrónicos nuevos o de otros datos para sincronizar, selecciona la prioridad normal de entrega.
- Prioridad alta. Esta es la prioridad predeterminada para mensajes de notificación. FCM intenta entregar los mensajes de alta prioridad de inmediato, lo que permite que el servicio de FCM active un dispositivo inactivo cuando sea posible y abra una conexión de red al servidor de tu app. Por lo general, las apps con alertas de llamadas de voz, mensajería instantánea o chat, por ejemplo, necesitan abrir una conexión de red y asegurarse de que FCM envíe el mensaje al dispositivo sin demora. Configura la prioridad alta si el mensaje es urgente y necesita la interacción inmediata del usuario, pero ten en cuenta que configurar los mensajes con prioridad alta consume más batería en comparación con los mensajes con prioridad normal.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Messaging está construido sobre GCM por lo que el consumo de memoria sería lo mismo.

Google recomienda que usemos Firebase Messaging, ya que la integración es más sencilla y todos los nuevos features que agreguen iran para Firebase Messaging, no para GCM que más adelante quedará obsoleta.

El consumo de memoria que tienes debe ser por otra cosas, puedes revisar esto ;) [Optimizar consumo bateria app android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120460/optimizar-consumo-bateria-app-android)